как установить одно изображение для CollapsingToolbarLayout и TabLayout?

как на картинке
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        app:expandedTitleTextColor="@color/white"
        app:collapsedTitleTextColor="@color/wb"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:titleCollapseMode="scale"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        android:layout_height="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutLargeSize">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/link"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/title_back"/>
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/goMain"
            app:navigationIconTint="@color/white"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_double_arrow_left_24"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:tabIconTint="@color/orange"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabInlineLabel="false"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabRippleColor="@color/wb2"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#000000"
            app:tabTextColor="#000000">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:icon="@drawable/crown"
                android:text="Коронные" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:icon="@drawable/question"
                android:text="Фразы" />

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

